# A good web hosting service that allows more then 1GB MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I was looking for a good mysql and php hosting service that allows more then 1GB MySQL databases for a cheap price and great service. can some one give some suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Go for a VPS. They don't limit on MySQL. You can have the database as large as your assigned disk space. Following are awesome and cheap VPS providers:

[Virpus](http://www.virpus.com/)
[VPSLatch](http://vpslatch.net)

Try finding coupon codes and you will save around 30% in this holiday season :). Both accept PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend totalchoicehosting.com. I've had multi-gig databases on their shared hosting before, but I'm guessing you want dedicated. Either way, I have used them for 6 years, and they are quite reliable and cheap.